# How to prevent some packages from automatically being removed?

Tags: apt, alsa

When I install transcriber 1.5.1.1-10 (which is a very old package last updated in 2004), My audio driver package which is current is depreciated to and older one:

```
Removing libsnack2-alsa (2.2.10-dfsg1-12build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsnack-alsa.
```

When I try to reinstall libsnack2-alsa, then transcriber is removed. Is there a way to prevent this?  Transcriber does not seem to work with the depreciated audio driver anyhow.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-mark manual transcriber` and then try..

Comment: Thanks for teaching me that.  It's great to know.  In the end, i just installed the windows/wine version.

Comment: yes please that!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apt-mark` to mark a package as manually installed so that it will not be automatically removed while removing some other package (because it is a dependency of this package hence is marked as `auto` installed).

For example, in my computer i am `mark`-ing `zenity` as manually installed:

```
% apt-mark showauto zenity    
zenity

% sudo apt-mark manual zenity
zenity set to manually installed.

% apt-mark showmanual zenity 
zenity
```

In you case, you need:

```
sudo apt-mark manual transcriber
```

Comment: This is a real solution but I’m wondering if the package when marked as manually installed is still able to be automatically updated or just ‘hold’ prevents update…

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-mark hold <package>`

For example:

`sudo apt-mark hold transcriber`

The opposite is:

`sudo apt-mark unhold <package>`

To show what packages are held:

`sudo apt-mark showhold`

Comment: +1 because the other solution only prevents package removal only if it was installed automatically as a dependency, whereas this solution really prevents package removal during upgrades (in rare cases apt can't find a clean upgrade path and will want to remove some packages during a release upgrade, even if said packages can be reinstalled afterwards)